# WiFi connection drops regularly

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using a AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter from Qualcomm and the wifi connection drops quite often. I also see `Oct 29 12:06:29 blueberry kernel: [156556.470659] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xbfa73844 flags=0x0000]` in logs. Is that related?

Log:

```
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.406687] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.422313] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.424938] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.425870] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.476925] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.477074] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:05:33 blueberry kernel: [156500.505865] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:06:29 blueberry kernel: [156556.470659] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xbfa73844 flags=0x0000]
Oct 29 12:06:29 blueberry kernel: [156556.534638] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xbf946844 flags=0x0000]
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.481220] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.496729] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.497951] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.500396] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.551203] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.551339] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:06:31 blueberry kernel: [156558.560296] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:06:40 blueberry kernel: [156567.452362] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:ac:f8:cc:06:1f:1a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.540676] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.555957] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.557367] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.559644] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.607672] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.607809] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:07:00 blueberry kernel: [156587.663649] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:08:03 blueberry kernel: [156650.672568] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xbeb03c44 flags=0x0000]
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.418856] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.434213] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.435646] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.437988] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.490687] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.490814] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:08:05 blueberry kernel: [156652.560667] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:08:45 blueberry kernel: [156692.189380] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:ac:f8:cc:06:1f:1a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Oct 29 12:09:25 blueberry kernel: [156732.382201] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0015 address=0xbe6c9444 flags=0x0000]
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.464442] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.479879] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.485007] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.487883] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.553131] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.553268] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:09:27 blueberry kernel: [156734.595892] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:10:23 blueberry kernel: [156790.787035] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=f8:1a:67:24:fe:39:ac:f8:cc:06:1f:1a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=192.168.178.20 LEN=545 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=24429 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49965 DPT=53671 LEN=525 
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.386720] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.402350] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.409080] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.413894] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.468160] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.468302] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:10:45 blueberry kernel: [156812.517929] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:10:50 blueberry kernel: [156817.217543] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:ac:f8:cc:06:1f:1a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.432877] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.448562] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.449774] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.452019] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.526884] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.527019] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:11:58 blueberry kernel: [156885.619664] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:12:55 blueberry kernel: [156942.450967] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:ac:f8:cc:06:1f:1a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.462978] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.478311] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.479588] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.481951] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.552896] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.553034] wlo1: associated
Oct 29 12:13:19 blueberry kernel: [156966.616583] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.544450] wlo1: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.560010] wlo1: send auth to ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.563313] wlo1: authenticated
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.563809] wlo1: associate with ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (try 1/3)
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.619683] wlo1: RX AssocResp from ac:f8:cc:06:1f:18 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 29 12:14:42 blueberry kernel: [157049.619833] wlo1: associated
```

Also to note is that the ping times leading up to the drop out increase:

```
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=1220ms TTL=127
Reply from 142.250.179.142: bytes=32 time=1521ms TTL=127
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 21.04.